# How to retroactively make a script run as root?

Tags: shell-script, sudo, root

I'm writing a shell script, that needs to be run with root privileges.

I can check if a user has root privileges with `sudo -nv || echo "no sudo"`, but that doesn't help me, if his credentials are still cached by `sudo`, but he didn't call my script with it. So I have no way of reacting to a user, not calling my script with sudo.

I could put `sudo` in front of every command that needs it, so just checking to see if the user has root privileges would be enough, but it seems to me, that there should be a better solution.

I'm looking for a command, that I can put into my script, that asks the user for root privileges and, if provided, executes the rest of the script, as if the user called it with root privileges in the first place.

What I want:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! command; then        # what I'm looking for
    echo "This script needs root privileges."
    exit 1
fi

mv /bin/cmd1 /bin/cmd2    # requires root
```

<sub>Edited 2 times</sub>

Comment: If the user is running the script, and you want them to sudo every command in the script, I don't understand why they wouldn't just sudo the script. Even if you sudo every command and redirect stdout/stdin/stderr properly, the user still has to enter root credentials either way.

Comment: "I'm looking for a command, that I can put into my script, that asks the user for root privileges and, if provided, executes the rest of the script," This is exactly what running the script as sudo does. Seems like reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @cremefraiche If the user runs the script with `sudo`, that would be completely fine. What I'm looking for is a failsafe if they don't do that. Checking for root privileges like I mentioned above does not ensure, that the user called my script with `sudo`, just that the credentials are cached. So I'm looking for something, that runs the script as if the user called it with `sudo` in the event, that he forgot.

Comment: I understand now, It seemed to me that you were checking if users were sudoers to prevent malicious use, which was hard for me to understand what the problem was. I have now updated my answer to achieve this effect without causing unnecessary lines of code to be run.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Test if you are root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215973/how-to-check-if-running-as-root-in-a-bash-script), and if not, restart with `sudo`, for example:

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]];
then
    exec sudo /bin/bash "$0" "$@"
fi
```

Comment: I thought about something like that. But I was a bit hesitant. Are there any security concerns? Will read the man page about `exec`. Didn't need it until now.

Comment: @Minix it's a shell builtin. Try `help exec`, or look at the man page of bash or sh. I think this is safe, but I am not sure.

Comment: Although cremefraiche's answer is the cleanest for what I needed, this answers the questions that I actually asked, so I will accept it.

Comment: probably want to pass the args too: `exec sudo /bin/bash "$0" "$@"`

Comment: @glennjackman Ah yes. I felt I was missing something.

Comment: This is probably plenty safe on any system that interprets the #! bangline - provided the proper `sudo` is in $PATH. If the presumption is that the bangline is interpreted then the `/bin/bash` bit is not really necessary though - `exec sudo "$0" "$@"` should be enough - and might be beneficial in that on those POSIX systems that dont handle the bangline but still do `sudo` it would probably still get the original script run with escalated privileges. Where `sudo` is iffy, POSIX also specs the `newgrp` command.

Comment: actually, I just looked at it again - `newgrp` is not a good alternative to `sudo` in a script context.

Comment: @mikeserv You just knocked off a foundation stone in my beliefs about POSIX systems. Are there any that don't handle the bangline?

Comment: well, the very first bullet in the shell command language spec reads: *The shell reads its input from a file (see `sh`), from the -coption or from the system() and popen() functions defined in the System Interfaces volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001. If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified.* I think that is a windows thing - POSIX is not all about unix-likes. I never tried to hunt it down, though. Thats also about what the shell itself does with it - not the kernel. POSIX doesnt tell kernels what to do, mostly.

Comment: @mikeserv "unspecified". I think I should quit scripting and start hunting nasal dragons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what it is. The Windows NT Subsystem failed to implement #! as that requires the loader to be in-kernel.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #!/bin/sudo /bin/bash

if ! command; then        # what I'm looking for
    echo "This script needs root privileges."
    exit 1
fi
```

she-bang isn't just for shells.
The file is accessed by the kernel - like any executable.
The kernel interprets a beginning '#!' an an indicator to
exec the first term with subsequent terms as a single argument to the new process.  Also to arrange that the script file path is passed to the process as argv[2].

The kernel will to do any advanced quoting or substitutions, merely separate based on space, tab, newline & null.

Comment: Note that on many systems, that won't work if you need to make it `#! /bin/sudo -uroot /bin/bash` because the default target user is otherwise not root. As on many systems shebangs allow only one argument after the path to the interpreter.

Comment: The example works on Linux & BSD. Of course you must configure sudo for your needs. If you modify my answer then it may no longer work (headslap emoji missing).   Linux & BSD kernel will examine a script header line like #!/bin/sudo -u root /bin/bash and exec /bin/sudo with argv[1] = "-u root /bin/bash" and argv[2]="/some/path/scriptfile"  IOW you can only pass 1 distinct argument (argv[1]) from the script header line